# Java Quartz 2.2.2 missing method

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I’m trying to create a task scheduler. I use Quartz. I followed [this](https://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/examples/Example1) example.
I make the dependence in maven (tested 2.2.1 and 2.2.2) and my class HelloJob implements Job.

I have

```
public class HelloJob implements Job{
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        // Say Hello to the World and display the date/time
        System.out.println("Hello World! - " + new Date());

        JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)
            .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
            .build();

    }
}
```

But I have the message:

```
The method newJob(Class<HelloJob>) is undefined for the type HelloJob
```

I tried to put the JobDetail declaration in my SimpleExample class, but the same error appears...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `newJob` is defined in `org.quartz.JobBuilder` as static. Add an static import in your class:

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
```